# drop down menu with delay - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have this [drop down menu](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksmakosz/yA6Lx/10/) that is supposed to have slightly delayed drop on hover, but it doesn't drop at all.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="overflow-hidden">one
            <div class="submenu">test</div>
        </li>
        <li class="overflow-hidden">two</li>
        <li class="overflow-hidden">three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.overflow-hidden {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submenu {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: You don't have any code saying that it should appear when you hover, therefore it doesn't appear. From what I can see.

Comment: It is in the jQuery which he hasn't added (only in the fiddle)

Comment: Why are you using overflow: hidden; and not display: none; for the dropdown?

Comment: Timer issue aside, you need to set your fiddle to run the javascript onload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two things totally wrong.

First: You're missing the jQuery ready event<sup>1</sup>.
Second: You didn't think about the scope<sup>2</sup>. $(this) is not available in setTimeout();

```
$(function(){ // (1a) jQuery ready start

    var menuWidth = $('.container').width();

    var menuHover = function(){

        var timer;

        $(".overflow-hidden").hover(

            function(){

                if(timer){
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }

                var temporary_element = $(this); // (2a) Store element in temporary variable

                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    temporary_element.css('overflow', 'visible'); // (2b) Get the stored element from the parent scope
                }, 200);

            },

            function(){

                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
                $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');

            }

        );

    };

    menuHover();

    $('.submenu').width(menuWidth);

}); // (1b) jQuery ready end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do to improve your code and make it work:

1. **Document Ready event.** you should initialize your code after the DOM has rendered, otherwise your code may be trying to attach events to things that aren't there yet!

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      menuHover();
      $('.submenu').width(menuWidth);
   });
   ```
2. **Scope.** Referring to `$(this)` inside the timer object will not be referring to what you think! Define the element you want to refer to at the top of your function, and you can then safely use this explicit definition in any functions defined within the same scope, and you won't have to worry about their own 'this' being something different.

   ```
   function () {
       var $listItem = $(this);

       if (timer) {
           clearTimeout(timer);
           timer = null;
       }
       timer = setTimeout(function () {
           $listItem.css('overflow', 'visible');
       }, 200);
   }
   ```
3. **Semantics.** Naming your list items `overflow-hidden` is semantically bad practice (that is a style not a name!) ... especially when the item is in the `overflow-visible` state!. It would be advisable to probably remove this altogether and target your list items by something like `.menu li` or giving them their own class eg. `menu-item`.

   ```
   var menuWidth = $('.container').width();
   var menuHover = function () {
       var timer;

       $(".menu li").hover(

       function () {
           var $listItem = $(this);

           if (timer) {
               clearTimeout(timer);
               timer = null;
           }
           timer = setTimeout(function () {
               $listItem.css('overflow', 'visible');
           }, 200);
       },
       function () {
           var $listItem = $(this);
           clearTimeout(timer);
           timer = null;
           $listItem.css('overflow', 'hidden');
       });};

   $(document).ready(function(){
       menuHover();
       $('.submenu').width(menuWidth);

   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS3 Transitions**

With the use of transition (-webkit,-moz,-ms) you don't even need javascript.

You can use the class or id to control sub elements.

**CSS**

```
#menu{

}
#menu>div{
 width:33%;
 float:left;
 height:20px;
 background-color:grey;
}
#menu>div>div:nth-child(1){
 line-height:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu>div>div:nth-child(2){
 overflow:hidden;
 height:0px;
 transition:height 700ms ease 500ms;
 /*
 the duration is 700milliseconds and the delay is 500milliseconds
 */
 background-color:#cc2;
 padding:0 16px;
}
#menu>div:hover>div:nth-child(2){
 height:20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
 <div><div>one</div><div>1</div></div>
 <div><div>two</div><div>2</div></div>
 <div><div>three</div><div>3</div></div>
</div>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/95wM2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
.overflow-hidden {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submenu {
    display: none;
}
.overflow-hidden:hover .submenu {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #999;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need jquery for this, you can use the pseudo class `:hover`

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yA6Lx/14/

```
.overflow:hover .submenu{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```